# Vue.js Typescript error when assigning a debounced function

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, web, frontend

I get the following error

`Type 'DebouncedFunc<(queryParams: QueryParams, page?: number) => Promise<void>>' is not assignable to type '(queryParams: QueryParams, page?: number) => Promise<void>'`

When I debounce a function in my Vue.js application.

```
created() {
    newData = _.debounce(newData 1000)
  }
```

Does anyone know a fix to this?

Ideally without using TS-ignore or doing a huge rewrite.

Thank you

Comment: _..debounce returns a different type that differs from your original `newData` type. I 
 would set a debounced function to a new property `newDataDebounced = _.debounce(newData, 1000)`

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . newData is this.newData, isn't it? It likely was wrongly typed. Since it's debounced function, it's supposed to have DebouncedFunc type, as the error implies. You wouldn't be able to use debounce features like `cancel` otherwise. Btw lodash debounce doesn't explicitly support promises, if you chain them then pick another promise-friendly implementation

Comment: alright I see, I just gotta ask chatGPT, lol thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

The error message you received indicates that the type of the debounced function you're trying to assign does not match the expected type.

To fix this error, you need to ensure that the debounced function is of the correct type.

One way to resolve this is to explicitly define the type of the debounced function using the DebouncedFunc type from the lodash library. For example, you can define type of the debounced function like this:

```
import { DebouncedFunc } from 'lodash'

created() {
  const debouncedNewData: DebouncedFunc<(queryParams: QueryParams, page?: number) => Promise<void>> = _.debounce(this.newData, 1000)
}
```

Alternatively, you can also define the type of the function that you're debouncing directly, like this:

```
created() {
  const newDataFn: (queryParams: QueryParams, page?: number) => Promise<void> = this.newData
  const debouncedNewData = _.debounce(newDataFn, 1000)
}
```